# How can one implement Google-signin and CSP rejection of inline stylesheets?

Tags: security, google-signin

I'm trying to enable the Content-Security-Policy header on my website. I have the following header set:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ 'sha256-W/8NeLkjrtPkUUfkFDNutwiyHLsvDJAxC+dO5tQP/90='; child-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com/
```

This works great in Firefox. That hash in the style-src section matches the inline styles that Google-signin uses. The problem is, per [Chromium Bug 546106](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546106), the hash is ignored because it's on a style, rather then a script. Worse still, from the comments Chrome/Chromium developers believe this is correct behavior, and is intended (that said, they haven't set it to "WONTFIX" yet).

I really don't want to enable 'unsafe-inline' if I don't have to.

Is there a way with Google-Signin to tell it not to use inline styling? Is there another way?

Comment: I presently am using "unsafe-inline". I really don't like it, so I'm keeping this open incase someone comes up with a workaround, or better yet Chromium decided to fix their implementation (I don't care that the doc is ambiguous, that's just a braindead way to implement it).